# Как разбить дату формата 0000-00-00 00:00:00 на составляющие

Tags: дата, php

Привет!

Есть задача установить на сайте таймер обратного отсчета, для него нужна дата окончания акции. В базе не хочется создавать кучу полей для даты и отдельных ее составляющих, по-этому хочу сосдать поле где будет указана дата окончания акции, ее после вывода нужно разбить на составляющие, т.е. 2013-20-10 10:32:12 и надо разбить на отдельные переменные: $year; $day; $month; $mday; $hours; $minutes; $seconds

Как это сделать?

Comment: не храните дату в виде строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может он посложнее хотел?

```
$newdate = "2013-20-10 10:32:12";

$date_explode = explode(" ", $newdate);

$date = explode("-", $date_explode[0]);
$time = explode(":", $date_explode[1]);

$year = $date[0];
$day = $date[1];
$month = $date[2];

$hours = $time[0];
$minutes = $time[1];
$seconds = $time[2];
```

Comment: Мсье знает толк... :D

Comment: оу оу оу, полегче =)

Answer (score 11):

`function` [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php)

Код на [`Ideone.com`](http://ideone.com/CPCT0Q)

P.S.: в вашей дате необходимо поменять местами месяц и день, так как функция `strtotime()` принимает такой формат.

Comment: да ты просто капитан очевидность! (сарказм) как сделать!

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev тяжело по ссылке перейти?

Answer (score 6):

Пользуйтесь классом DateTime, [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Answer (score 2):

```
$newdate = "2013-20-10 10:32:12";

$dt_explode = explode(' ',$newdate);

list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $dt_explode[0]);

list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':',$dt_explode[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Для этого есть функция strtotime, которая преобразует строку в метку времени. Результат присвоить переменной, и указывать её вторым параметром к функции date.

```
$newdate = "2013-20-10 10:32:12";
date('m',$newdate)
```

покажет 10 (десятый месяц, октябрь)

```
date('s',$newdate)
```

покажет 12 (секунд).
Да, и из базы mysql можно доставать не всю дату, а допустим из поля date типа datetime можно указать в запросе MONTH(date), достанет только месяц. Можно задать день, год, день недели, день от начала года и т.д., вариантов много.